# Scan QR code if multiple QR code showing on screen

Tags: java, android, android-camera, zxing, qr-code

I am developing one android sample application as an academic project where I need to scan QR code, I used QR scan code library and I am able to detect QR code successfully if on screen there is only one QR code.

Right I want to scan QR code although same QR code showing at multiple places on screen at a time. For an example, On my laptop screen QR code image looks like below mentioned images.All QR codes are same, there is no difference between them. 
Consider below images which are having 6 and 4 same QR code but together with some padding. Now, user focus or put camera anywhere on screen it should be scanned. If camera focus on multiple QR code at a time then scan any one of them.

Solution which I am thinking

1) We can limit the area of camera preview frame and try to get QR code, but as per my requirement it is not feasible.
2) Shall I apply any image processing algorithm on image first?

Please help me how can I achieve with robustness. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

**2 Images :**

[image]

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 2):

BoofCV's QR scanner easily handles multiple QR codes right next to each other.

https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Example_Detect_QR_Code

I rand the Android demo on your images and it read them just fine. Each QR code is treated as independent even though they have the same message. You get the location and message of each one.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.boofcv.android&hl=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cordova plugin for anroid, though it is under development. but it scans multiple qr code based on structure multiple qr code array.

Cordova plugin: https://github.com/behestee/cordova-plugin-multipartqrcodescanner

You will better understand how to create and read a structure multiple qr code array at here: http://programresource.net/en/2013/05/04/2202.html